# Using triple integral to find the volume of a sphere with cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm reviewing for my Calculus 3 midterm, and one of the practice problems I'm going over asks to find the volume of the below solid 1. by using a triple integral with spherical coordinates, and 2. by using a triple integral with cylindrical coordinates.

I'm able to do the integral with spherical coordinates, but I'm getting confused on the one with cylindrical coordinates.  In my notes I have written that the cylindrical volume should be: $$dv = r\ dr\ d\theta\ dz$$
Looking at the solution to this problem, it is integrated in the order: $dz\ dr\ d \theta$ , I'm not sure what the point is of changing the integration order?
Also, the bounds in the solution for the integral with respect to $z$ are from $0$ to $\sqrt{4-r^2}$, and I'm not sure where that is coming from either?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know the equation of such part of the sphere is $$z^2=4-(x^2+y^2),x\in[0..2],y\in[0..2]$$ But $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and then $z=\sqrt{4-r^2}$. The ranges of our new variables are : $$\theta|_0^{\pi/2}, r|_0^2, z|_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}$$ So we have to evaluate $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}dv$$

Comment: Nice! and quick...$\quad+1\quad$;-)

Comment: We haven't learned Jacobian determinant yet.

Comment: What does it do?  Is it something I need to look up?  In my notes from class when we covered cylindrical and spherical coordinates there were just a few basic examples of solving a few definite integrals for each, but nothing about Jacobian determinant

Comment: The above graph is in Cartesian.  There is no other information given except for that graph.  Two questions follow the graph: 1. Evaluate an integral in spherical coordinates for the volume, and 2. Evaluate an integral in cylindrical coordinates for the volume.  
I was able to compose and solve the first one no problem, but I'm pretty confused on the given solution in the answer key for the second.

Comment: Okay, so it is given in dv=rdrdzdθ.  I see where you are doing the substitution of r^2 for (x^2+y^2) into the equation for a sphere, but where does the equation r^2=x^2+y^2 come from?

Comment: There are some relations between coordinates. Two of them are $x=r\cos t, y=r\sin t$ which lead us to $x^2+y^2=r^2$ relating the Cartesian and Cylindrical ones.

Comment: Okay...sorry, but where are these coming from: x=rcost,y=rsint

Comment: @PseudoPsyche: They come from when you want to find the coordinates $(x,y)$ of an arbitrary point lying on a circle with radius $r$ centered at the origin. :-)

Comment: Okay,so I'm assuming I should just memorize the r^=x^2+y^2 thing for my exam tomorrow morning then? :P

Comment: @PseudoPsyche: I think you can. But it's better to note some of the above formula first and then the relation you noted next and then $dv$ above. I hope you have a paved exam. :-)

Comment: Alright, thanks!  This is the last section we covered before the exam, and it's the only thing I'm really iffy on so overall I don't think it'll be too bad.